# Why is non-static variable behaving like static?

Tags: javascript, function, static

```
function emergency() {
    var ambulance = 100;
    var callAmbulance = function() { alert(ambulance); }
    ambulance++;
    return callAmbulance;
}
var accident = emergency();
accident(); // alerts 101
```

I am referring to the variable `'ambulance'`.

When I call `accident();` it should call `emergency()` which should use the declared variable `'ambulance'` [considering the global scope thing in javascript, still it could set the value to global] but its using old value 101 instead of setting again back to 100 - behaving more like `static` var.

What's the Explanation?

Comment: Why would it use an old value? Also, calling `accident` does not call `emergency`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Expecting 100 as output.

Comment: `emergency` will return `callAmbulance`. `callAmublance` returns the value for `ambulance`. You `++`'d `ambulance`, so the value is 101.

Comment: what makes you think that `accident();` should call `emergency()` ?

Comment: The title of your question is kinda misleading.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is called a `closure`. It means a function can access variables declared in outer functions (or in the global scope). It retains access even after the 'parent' function has returned. What you need to understand is that you don't get a **copy**. The changes performed on that variable are visible to your inner function, which in theory means you could have multiple functions sharing access to the same variable.

```
function f () {
  var x = 0;

  function a() { x += 1; }
  function b() { x += 2; }
  function show() { console.log(x); }

  return {a:a, b:b, show:show};
}

var funcs = f();
funcs.a();
funcs.b();
funcs.show(); // 3
```

One thing to be aware of is that a subsequent call to `f` will create a new scope. This means a **new** x variable will be created (new a, b, show functions will be created as well).

```
var newFuncs = f();
newFuncs.a();
newFuncs.show(); // 1

funcs.a();
funcs.show(); // 4
```

So, how do you get a copy? Create a new scope.

```
function g () {
  var x = 0;
  var a;

  (function (myLocal) {
    a = function () { myLocal += 1; }
  }(x));

  x += 200;

  return a;
}
```

JS only has pass-by-value so when you call the anonymous function, the `x`variable's value will be copied into the `myLocal` parameter. Since `a` will always use the `myLocal` variable, not `x`, you can be certain that changes performed on the `x` variable will not affect your `a` function.

If, by any chance, you're coming from a PHP background you are probably used to do something like

```
use (&$message)
```

to allow modifications to be reflected in your function. In JS, this is happening by default.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a function definition which is not compiled at this time:

```
var callAmbulance = function() { alert(ambulance); }
```

And before you are sending it to the called function, you are incrementing the num:

```
ambulance++;
```

And then you are sending it to the called function:

```
return callAmbulance;
```

But whether you are sending it there or not, it doesn't matter. The below statement executes or compiles the function:

```
var accident = emergency();
```

And this takes in the current `ambulance` value which is `101` after the increment. This is an expected behaviour in creating function but not executing it. Please let me know, if you didn't understand this behaviour. I will explain it more clearly.